# What impact does partial update has on Solr Index Size and Performance?

Tags: solr, solrj, solr4

I'm having a "*version*" in my solr schema. However, I'm not utilizing the partial update feature. Moreover, we do not need the transaction log for our schema.

The field I'm talking about is:

```
<field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
```

Does having this field that makes it partial update friendly has any impact on the Index Size and Performance of the Solr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the fields in the document you want to partially update are marked as stored=”true”. Solr need that in order to update single fields, it read the stored data and uses them to reconstruct the document.
Practically the document will be removed and indexed again.

#### Size

Size matters. :) if you had no intentio to store all your data in the first place, then it makes a difference otherwise is just the same.

#### Performance

Lucene underneath always requires to delete the old document and index the new one, so in terms of speed you only save the tranfer time of your data to the server.

check this link for some info: http://solr.pl/en/2012/07/09/solr-4-0-partial-documents-update/

plus this one: [Partial Update of documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15161903/partial-update-of-documents)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Does it require all fields to be stored? Moreover, does it have any real impact on performance for searching?

Comment: Yes it requires all fields to be stored, and it's the only way if you think about it. if you update any of the fields solr need all the others to read the values you are not providing for update.

Comment: About performance there is no impact on the search itself. the update change nothing as itøs like any other type of update, the fact that you store the data may slow down the process of reading the data back to your client if you read many fields.