# How to add new field for existing solr documents without re indexing?

Tags: solr

I have assign pageRank score to every document in my index. I need to add a new field "pageRank" and assign a value to this field for every document in the index. How can i achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update a new field to existing document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11791803/update-a-new-field-to-existing-document)

Comment: In practice, you have to index a document with the new field value. There is no way around submitting the value to the index. If all fields are stored or have docValues enabled, you can use an atomic update and only submit the new field's value. Otherwise you'd have to submit the complete document again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use External File Fields. This does not require you to reindex but you have to reload the cache or do a commit to load the external fields.

See: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Working+with+External+Files+and+Processes